# Is there a way to inline function that is passed to a macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

For example, I can write a macro like this:

```
(defmacro apply-one [f]
  `(~f 1))
(println (apply-one (fn [x] (+ 42 x))))
; => 43
```

But that macro expansion results in extra function calls:

```
(macroexpand '(apply-one (fn [x] (+ 42 x))))
; => ((fn [x] (+ 42 x)) 1)
```

Is there a way to "inline" the function that was passed, so that:

```
(macroexpand '(apply-one (fn [x] (+ 42 x))))
; => (+ 42 1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There might be a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @exupero I'm trying to speed up the macro-generated code. The exact code is this: https://gist.github.com/Rogach/909f47bdd22b5d0ba91a1626d8218481, and I'm trying to reduce duplication in `cond` branches by extracting repeating parts into branches.

Comment: @exupero Everything between `doseq` and `aset lights i` is exactly the same, and it would be nice to avoid repeating the code.

Comment: So what you have in mind is either the function ```(fn [i] true)```, ```(fn [i] false)``` or ```(fn [i] (not (aget lights i)))```, is that correct?

Comment: @Rulle Yes, like that.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question you actually asked, I would say: don't do this. Inlining is one of the things the JVM does well, and you shouldn't make your code more complicated and less readable to guarantee that something gets inlined.

Your original problem statement, posted in the comments, has a much cleaner solution: don't duplicate anything! Instead of writing a `cond` expression with three almost-identical clauses, use a `cond` to set a variable for the only part that varies, and then do the rest of the body unconditionally, using the variable you set.

```
(let [compute (case command
                "turn on" (constantly true)
                "turn off" (constantly false)
                "toggle" not)]
  (doseq [x (range x1 (inc x2))
          y (range y1 (inc y2))
          :let [i (+ (* y W) x)]]
    (aset lights i (compute (aget lights i)))))
```

Comment: I do appreciate clean code, and your version is indeed much cleaner than macro-based alternative with scary inlining. However, it is also much slower - because we are calling functions over and over again. I understand that microbenchmarking is quite evil, but in this case results seem to be clear - macro-based version works in 8.6s, your version took 282s. Obviously, the JVM has its limits. Here's the code I used to benchmark: https://gist.github.com/Rogach/4f2366bfa300042b85b0ebaeb066a823

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newcomer to Clojure, so the following solution is both horrifying and  beautiful to me. But it's a solution nonetheless.

```
(defmacro apply-one [f]
  (eval `(~f 1)))
(println (apply-one (fn [x] `(+ ~x 42))))
; => 43
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(apply-one (fn [x] `(+ ~x 42)))))
; => (clojure.core/+ 1 42)
```

Comment: s/m3/apply-one/

Comment: @cfrick - Thanks!